# Why does a local image in a UIWebView take forever to load on an iPad?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in a navigation controller.  It pulls html from an xml file and then displays the html.  The html contains code to grab local images via `<img src="image.png" />`.  On the iPhone Simulator, the UIWebView displays the text and images at the same time.  However, there is a big delay on the iPad:

[image: Waiting for images to load...]

A few seconds later the images load:

[image: Finally loaded!]

How can I get rid of this nasty delay?

Code:

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Blah blah %@ <img src='image.png'> %@", [self.questionsAndAnswers objectAtIndex:0], [self.questionsAndAnswers objectAtIndex:1]];
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

The UIWebView is connected via Storyboard.

Edit:  despite my comments, this actually happens with any image.  I even tried loading it into a basic UIWebView with no other html!

Comment: Can you post the code where you load and then display the html?

Comment: Also, how large are your images?

Comment: I can't get to the code right now.   The images are fairly small (300x300 at the most).   I can load another UIWebView called by another UITableViewCell with a larger image and still get the same results

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing the code, but I'm going to guess that you're getting delay because the images are getting cached.  One way to work around this is to preload the html w/image in the background.

Comment: I tried loading it (but not showing it) on the first screen of my app, thinking it would load faster on this screen, but it didn't.

Comment: What method are you using to load it?

Comment: @mydogisbox I put the code in the question

Comment: I'm not finding anything that would help you.  It appears that loading images just has some delay.  Recommended solutions are preloading the html (which doesn't look like it would help you) and loading the html directly from file instead of loading it first into a string, but this also doesn't help you.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Do any optimization details on the images matter?

Comment: Probably. The larger the file size the longer the time time would be my guess.

Comment: Not in this case.  The file that has a 200kb size loads instantly.  If I replace it with a 6kb image, it takes long to load.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the 6kb image compared to the dimensions of the space you're putting it in? i.e. does it have to be scaled?

Comment: @mydogisbox I am not scaling.  Small image: 228x228.  Large image:443x396

Comment: I would post this question in the apple forums if I were you.

Comment: Oh I have :)  I am probably going to have to use up a developer support incident for this, though

Comment: are you using any external resources or css???

Comment: @DimplePanchal  Ok I think I narrowed the problem down.  Any image in the UIWebView takes a long time to load if there is blank space at the bottom of the UIWebView.  In other words, if there is no text to scroll down to, the images take forever to load.

Comment: I seemed to have fixed the problem by deleting and readding my UIWebView.  @mydogisbox, please make an answer so I can award you the bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to try:

- Preload the html (useful if you don't have to generate any of it on the fly)
- Preload the image (in order to cache it)
- Make sure caching is off
- Make sure there isn't a lot of image processing going on (resizing etc)
- Make sure your images aren't too large (probably anything over 100k should be checked
- If all else fails, try to make a minimal example by slowly removing parts or by rebuilding the view piece by piece